# ¿Cómo posicionar divs horizontalmente, una de ellas con texto?

Tags: html5

Estoy intentando alinear horizontalmente cajitas (`div`), pero una de ellas tiene un texto en su interior, y se me desplaza hacia abajo. El código es el que sigue:

```css
div {
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 200px;
 height: 160px;
 margin: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Sombras</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/modernizr-custom.js">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="caja1"></div>
 <div id="caja2"></div>
 <div id="caja3"></div>
 <div id="caja4"><p>Texto de prueba</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

¿Por qué la caja del texto se desplaza? ¿Es posible solucionarlo?.

He probado a establecer un `position: absolute` a la caja del texto, y se soluciona el problema cuando lo veo en el navegador en ventana grande, pero en ventana pequeña (móvil), la caja se va a la izquierda.

Answer (score 2):

El problema se debe básicamente al `vertical-align` que los elementos inline tienen, el cual origina que la línea base del componente sea alineado con la  línea base de la caja, originando un margen "invisible" que causa que la caja se salga de flujo. Ésta propiedad es bastante confusa para entender, te recomiendo le eches un vistazo a [ésta info](http://www.htmlhelp.com/es/reference/css/text/vertical-align.html) para entender mejor sus valores. Dándole un `vertical-align` como `top`, `middle` o `bottom` solucionas éste inconveniente.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="caja1"></div>
<div id="caja2"></div>
<div id="caja3"></div>
<div id="caja4">
  <p>Texto de prueba</p>
</div>
```

Comment: + 1 - estaba escribiendo casi la misma respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar puedes usar `float: left;`

```css
#caja1,#caja2,#caja3,#caja4{
border: 1px solid black;
 width: 200px;
 height: 160px;
 margin: 20px;
  float: left;
  }
```

```html
 <div id="caja1"></div>
 <div id="caja2"></div>
 <div id="caja3"></div>
 <div id="caja4"><p>Texto de prueba</p></div>
```

respondiendo:

> ¿Por qué la caja del texto se desplaza?

`inline-block` se aplica a un contenedor, en este caso no existe algun contendor que contenga todos los `divs`

Comment: ¿Y la razón del por qué la caja se sale de flujo?

Comment: @guzgarcia no me di cuenta, ya edite mi respuesta, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Viendo que ya han respondido la pregunta y solucionado el conflicto, aporto una alternativa mas al caso, utilizando [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Que dependiendo de lo que estes intentando hacer con las cajitas puede darte mayor flexibilidad (valga la redundancia) en determinadas ocasiones.

```css
.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box > div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div><p>Texto de prueba</p></div>
</div>
```